# Compiling ion library without android-support to avoid conflict

Tags: android, android-library

I'm trying to compile the ion library into my project like this:

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
```

but the problem is its dependencies there is also support-v4 library that I already imported in a subproject and that I cannot remove from there.

Is there a way to compile/import the ion library without taking the support library? I remember there was a sort a way like:

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6:support-v4'
```

to remove it but I don't remember the exact syntax and I can't find anything about it... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found! :)

You need to add before the android declaration, in the gradle file:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```